# fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'CL/sycl.hpp': No such file or directory

Tags: visual-studio, intel, intel-oneapi, onevpl, intel-video-processing

I’m working on oneVPL samples from this GitHub repository (https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneAPI-samples ) and I’m trying to build dpcpp-blur sample. I am getting the below error:

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'CL/sycl.hpp': No such file or directory
```

PS: I am working on Windows 10 & I’ve downloaded the latest version of intel oneapi base toolkit. I’ve initialized the oneapi environment. I’ve checked the path too.

Any suggestions to resolve this issue?

Comment: Did the file get downloaded? Can you see it from the github web version?

Comment: @rajah9 Yes the file got downloaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your information, the oneVPL sample `dpcpp-blur` is not Windows supported.

You can try this sample in Ubuntu.